# Filter with 3 and more criteria

Tags: excel, vba, filter, contain

Good day everyone!
I extremely need to use filter with 3 criteria, but by default there is just 2. So how could I find cells (in certain column) which contain "AGD" or "mrk" or "macro" using standard excel or vba?
thx in advance

Comment: You need to pass an `Array("AGD, "mrk, "macro")` as parameter for the filter and filter by values.

Comment: @mehow thanks, but where is filter by values? I've tried it for text filters, but it doesn't work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seya, set correct range and Field and try this

```
Sub FilterByMoreThanTwo()

  Range("A1:C1").AutoFilter ' set your range

  Range("A1:C1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("AGD", "mrk", "macro"), _ 
                              Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

or if you want to be able to use an array variable that's made of variables

```
Sub FilterByMoreThanTwo()

    Range("A1:C1").AutoFilter ' set your range

    Dim arr(3) As String
    arr(0) = "AGD"
    arr(1) = "mrk"
    arr(2) = "macro"

    Range("A1:C1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```